# Operating on a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

A very short version of my list named "fire" is

`fire = {{0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0}}`.

For the first sublist `Length[TakeWhile[fire[[1]], # < 20 &]]`, calculates the number of preceding "0" before 20 shows up. In this case I get 3. The number of preceding 0 before 20 or the end of the sublist shows up is my ultimate goal.

Since my true list has 1000 of these sublists of six numbers I tried to map the function `Length[TakeWhile[fire...]`. However, `MapApply` or `Map` did not work. The problem seems to identy the subsequent elements of fire within the expression. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `Length@First@SplitBy[#, 20] & /@ fire`

Comment: `f[x_] := Length[TakeWhile[x, # < 20 &]];
f /@ fire`

Comment: Unclear:  are 0s the *only* possible entries before the 20?

Comment: In case we're counting 0s but other values might occur before the 20:  `Count[#, 0] &  /@ (First /@ (SplitBy[#, 20] & /@ fire))`

Comment: Does the built-in work? `LengthWhile[#, EqualTo[0]] & /@ fire`? Assuming the only possible values are `0` or `20`, at least, if the lists here are good examples.

Comment: `FirstPosition[Append[#, 20], 20] - 1 & /@ fire` Works for any preceding values including zero and also works for list not containing 20.

Comment: `Flatten@ParallelMap[FirstPosition[#, 20, Length[#]] - 1 &, fire2]` is a little faster. ;)

Comment: Let me give my 5 cents into this discussion: `Position[fire[[1]], 20][[1, 1]] - 1` yields the expected `3`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch yours is by far the fastest!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. All comments are very enlightening. I tried them all. The only numbers that occur are 0 or 20. The first solution by Martin works fine but has a problem if the 20 occurs in the first position.  This problem does not occur in the second solution by Martin.  The first solution by Rudy works very good as well but the second yields too low value. Once again thank you very much David, thorimur,  Alexei

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0}};
```

Using `SequenceCount`

```
SequenceCount[#, {0 .., Except[0]}, Overlaps -> True] & /@ list
```

> {3, 3, 2}

Another test

```
SequenceCount[ {{1}, {0, 1}}, {0 .., Except[0]}, Overlaps -> True] & /@ list
```

> {0, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `1` and `SequencePosition`:

```
Replace[list, x_ :> Length@SequencePosition[x, {0 .., 20}], {1}]
```

> `{3, 3, 2}`